# Why are there holes in a mesh when I am rendering with my GPU in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, mesh, gpu

I have a big peoblem. It started to happen few weeks ago, which makes me think that it is because of the update to Windows 10. (Also I had trouble with Photoshop.)

The problem is, I can render all OK with my CPU. It's an i5 7400. But when I try to render with my GPU I have really annoying holes in my mesh.

Here is an example:

[image: GPU rendered image with missing parts of table]

I rendered this with my GPU, wich is a Sapphire R9 280 dual x.
You can see the HDRI behind the table.

And this is what I got from my CPU:

[image: same image rendered with CPU, without any missing parts]

In the past I had the same result with these two options, but this started to happen few weeks ago.

Here is another example. I didn't even have a complex material here, it's just a diffuse shader:

[image: sculpture rendered with GPU]

And there are more situations when everything looks horrible. I am really worried because if I want to make a nice and heavy render, I must do it with the CPU, but it would take a lot longer time...

Please, if somone knows what to do, tell me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Gpu drivers fault, I guess... Weird.

Comment: I tried with the latest version, the previous version and a downgrade to december 2017 version of AMD drivers, Nothing works, I tried to update windows too, and nothing. Now I have the latest version of windows fall creators and AMD drviers